# Accessing Facebook ads manager account logs me out with error "FB internal Thrift over HTTP"

Tags: facebook

When using my Facebook account I don't have any problem but when I try to access my ***Facebook ads manager*** account it logs me out with an error **FB internal Thrift over HTTP** [Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4doU.png) and clicking on See more only shows an IP address (***2a03:2880:22ff:6::face:b00c***) which seems to be of Facebook itself. Does that mean that Facebook is trying to log into my account and logs me out as well. How to solve it?

Clicking on Yes or No redirect to change password option but the issue is still there after I have changed the password twice.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this? I am having the same problem, although I can't help, there do seem to be a few more people over on reddit experiencing the same thing. https://www.reddit.com/r/PPC/comments/qrznwr/fb_internal_thrift_over_http_ip/

Comment: @Ted Thanks for the link the information given in reddit worked.